# What to change from operator+ to operator-

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, bigint

So for a BigInt problem, I want to add an operator-, how would I change my code for that? It's just for practice, but I'm having some problem finding the solution for change.

Here is my operator+:

```
int carry = 0;
    int sum;
    BigInt result;
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit1 = number.rbegin();
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit2 = operand.number.rbegin();
    while ( (rit1 != number.rend()) || (rit2 != operand.number.rend()) )
    {
        sum = 0;

        if (rit1 != number.rend())
        {
            sum += *rit1;
            rit1++;
        }

        if (rit2 != operand.number.rend())
        {
            sum += *rit2;
            rit2++;
        }

        sum += carry;
        result.number.push_front(sum % 10);
        carry = sum / 10;
    }

    if (carry > 0)
        result.number.push_front(carry);

    return result;
```

Comment: How about including the prototype and the terminating brace? Anyway, nice wall of code.

Comment: I don't think OP is having problems declaring an operator.. It's tagged `BigInt` so they have the addition operation working for `BigInt` and would like to know how to do the subtraction operation.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames, you are correct.

Comment: Why not build `operator-` in terms of `x + -y`...?  If you don't have a negation operator yet, seems good to add, and easier.  Then you'll need to fix your `operator+` to handle negative numbers, but it's not much use to anyone if it can't.

Comment: @TonyD, I didn't think of that. Thank you. I got it working now. If you provide an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @AustinAllenJulio: added as answer.  You're welcome.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not build `operator-` in terms of `x + -y`...? If you don't have a negation operator yet, seems good to add, and easier. Then you'll need to fix your `operator+` to handle negative numbers, but it's not much use to anyone if it can't.